# Non-planar robot Dynamics error using Roy Featherstone's Spatial toolbox

Tags: robotic-arm, dynamics, simulation

I am using this code to test robot dynamics of above robot using Spatial Toolbox function:

```
FDab(rob, [0;0;0], [0;0;0], [0;0;0]) %a_grav = [0,0,-9.81]
```

But it gives error:

```
Error using  *
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in FDab (line 49)
    a{i} = Xup{i} * -a_grav + c{i};
```

This is because Xup is 6x6 double whereas a_grav is 1x3.

The 3 link non-planar robot used is given as:

```
rob.NB = 3;
rob.parent = [0:2];
rob.jtype = { 'R', 'R', 'R' }
model.gravity = [0 0 0];
rob.Xtree{1} = rotx(1.57) * xlt([0 0 0]);
rob.Xtree{2} = roty(1.57) * xlt([0.15,0,0]);
rob.Xtree{3} = xlt([0.34 0 0]);
ax1=0.03; ay1=0.03; az1=0.03;
ax2=0.28; ay2=0.05; az2=0.05;
ax3=0.2; ay3=0.05; az3=0.05;
rob.I{1} = mcI( 1, [0 0 -0.02], 1/12*[ay1^2+az1^2 0 0; 0 ax1^2+az1^2 0; 0 0 ax1^2+ay1^2] )
rob.I{2} = mcI( 4, [0.14 0 0], 4/12*[ay2^2+az2^2 0 0; 0 ax2^2+az2^2 0; 0 0 ax2^2+ay2^2] )
rob.I{3} = mcI( 3, [0.1 0 0], 3/12*[ay3^2+az3^2 0 0; 0 ax3^2+az3^2 0; 0 0 ax3^2+ay3^2] )
rob.appearance.base = ...
  { 'box', [-0.2 -0.3 -0.2; 0.2 0.3 -0.07] };
rob.appearance.body{1} = ...
    { 'cyl', [0 0 0; 0.11 0 0], 0.05, ...
      'cyl', [0 0 -0.06; 0 0 0.06], 0.06 };
rob.appearance.body{2} = ...
    { 'cyl', [0 0 0; 0.34 0 0], 0.05, ...
      'cyl', [0 0 -0.06; 0 0 0.06], 0.06 };
rob.appearance.body{3} = ...
    { 'cyl', [0 0 0; 0.26 0 0], 0.05, ...
      'cyl', [0 0 -0.06; 0 0 0.06], 0.06 };
showmotion(rob)
```

How can I overcome the error?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I cannot recreate your issue, but you haven't posted all the steps you're taking, so I'm not sure if I'm following exactly what you've done.

What version are you using? I have Spatial_v2, and the README says (C) 2012. You have:

```
Error using  *
Inner matrix dimensions must agree.
Error in FDab (line 49)
    a{i} = Xup{i} * -a_grav + c{i};
```

But that line isn't line 49 in my version of `FDab`, it's line 47 in my code.

**Regardless**, note that the `FDab` function doesn't get `model.gravity` directly; it calls `get_gravity(model)` and that function will return a 6x1 vector if the check `size(model.Xtree{1},1) == 3` returns **FALSE** (lines 18 and 21 in `get_gravity()`)

This could be where you're having the issue - you're saying your robot is non-planar, but it's passing the planar check `size(model.Xtree{1},1) == 3` in `get_gravity()`. **This is the only way you get `a_grav` as a  3x1 vector from `get_gravity()`.**

I don't know how you initialized your robot, but I managed to run your code without issue if I took the following steps:

1. Not provided in the OP: `rob = singlebody;`
2. I'm not sure if the above is correct because I had to manually empty `appearance.body` in order to stop errors when running your code: `rob.appearance.body = []`
3. Copy/paste your code from `rob.NB = 3;` to `showmotion(rob)`; I got no errors and the animation played correctly.
4. You don't set gravity in the code snippet you provided, so I set: `rob.gravity = [0,0,-9.81]`
5. I ran the code in question:

```matlab
>> FDab(rob, [0;0;0], [0;0;0], [0;0;0])

ans =

  -59.1867
   -3.8828
    6.9148
```

I would guess you've got an issue with your model declaration or configuration as there are steps required to get your snippet to run. Try `clear all` to flush your session variables and re-running the code. It might be something you had tried previously is still in memory and that's screwing up your results.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I was writing gravity as: `rob.gravity = [0,0,-9.81]` but now I have changed it to: `a_grav = get_gravity(rob);` and now it is working fine.