# Forward Kinematics of non-planar robot using Roy Featherstone's Spatial Toolbox

Tags: robotic-arm, kinematics, simulation, forward-kinematics

I have a non-floatbase 3 DOF non-planar robot whose forward kinematics I need to compute using Spatial Toolbox. The code for this purpose is `p = fbkin(q)` but as my robot is 3 DOF (q is 3x1 vector e.g. `[0;0;0]`) and non-floatbase, I am unable to get kinematics of the model and get this error:

> fbkin([0;0;0]) %input

```
Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in fbkin>fwdkin (line 49)
c4 = cos(q(4));  s4 = sin(q(4));

Error in fbkin (line 41)
    o1 = fwdkin( i1 );
```

My robot is:

```
rob.NB = 3;
rob.parent = [0:2];
rob.jtype = { 'R', 'R', 'R' }

model.gravity = [0 0 0];

rob.Xtree{1} = rotx(1.57) * xlt([0 0 0]);
rob.Xtree{2} = roty(1.57) * xlt([0.15,0,0]);
rob.Xtree{3} = xlt([0.34 0 0]);

ax1=0.03; ay1=0.03; az1=0.03;
ax2=0.28; ay2=0.05; az2=0.05;
ax3=0.2; ay3=0.05; az3=0.05;

rob.I{1} = mcI( 1, [0 0 -0.02], 1/12*[ay1^2+az1^2 0 0; 0 ax1^2+az1^2 0; 0 0 ax1^2+ay1^2] )
rob.I{2} = mcI( 4, [0.14 0 0], 4/12*[ay2^2+az2^2 0 0; 0 ax2^2+az2^2 0; 0 0 ax2^2+ay2^2] )
rob.I{3} = mcI( 3, [0.1 0 0], 3/12*[ay3^2+az3^2 0 0; 0 ax3^2+az3^2 0; 0 0 ax3^2+ay3^2] )

rob.appearance.base = ...
  { 'box', [-0.2 -0.3 -0.2; 0.2 0.3 -0.07] };

rob.appearance.body{1} = ...
    { 'cyl', [0 0 0; 0.11 0 0], 0.05, ...
      'cyl', [0 0 -0.06; 0 0 0.06], 0.06 };

rob.appearance.body{2} = ...
    { 'cyl', [0 0 0; 0.34 0 0], 0.05, ...
      'cyl', [0 0 -0.06; 0 0 0.06], 0.06 };

rob.appearance.body{3} = ...
    { 'cyl', [0 0 0; 0.26 0 0], 0.05, ...
      'cyl', [0 0 -0.06; 0 0 0.06], 0.06 };

showmotion(rob)
```

How can I use the fbkin function with 3x1 joint angle vector?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got to open the functions you're trying to use and look through them if you're getting errors. You said you are trying to get the forward kinematics of your robot, and that it's a non-floatbase, and that you've got a 3x1 vector of joint values `q`.

Yet you're using `fbkin` which, if you type `help fbkin` into the console, will state (added bold for things relevant to you):

> `>> help fbkin`
>
> fbkin  Forward and Inverse Kinematics **of Floating Base**
>
> [x,xd]=fbkin(q,qd,qdd) calculates the forward kinematics, and [q,qd,qdd]=fbkin(x,xd) calculates the inverse kinematics, **of a spatial floating base constructed by `floatbase`.**

So, right away, if you didn't use `floatbase` to make your base, then you're using the wrong function. The rest of the `help` message continues:

> **The vectors q**, qd and qdd are the joint position, velocity and acceleration variables **for the six joints forming the floating base**; x is the 13-element singularity-free state vector used by FDfb and IDfb; and xd is its derivative.

And here it says it's a floating base, so naturally it's got six degrees of freedom, so if you're going to do anything with it then you can imagine the base as having six joints (x/y/z roll/pitch/yaw) and that's what this function is looking for when it uses `q` as an input. It is *not* saying that this is for use with a robot arm or a kinematic tree or anything else. Just the floating base.

Continuing:

> The component parts of x are: a unit quaternion specifying the orientation of the floating-base frame relative to the fixed base, a 3D vector giving the position of the origin of the floating-base frame, and the spatial velocity of the floating base expressed in fixed-base coordinates.

That is the output for the forward kinematics code - quaternion orientation and x/y/z position, and spatial velocity, which is angular and linear velocities. The remainder of the `help` comment talks about different ways to call the function and things to look out for with regards to singularities.

This is not the code that's going to do forward kinematics for a robot arm. It's doing kinematics for a base.

You need to go to the `\dyanmics` folder and look at some of the `FD__` functions; those are the `F`orward `D`ynamics functions. Actually I was going to suggest you try `FDab` and I remembered that was at the core of your [other question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/19129/non-planar-robot-dynamics-error-using-roy-featherstones-spatial-toolbox), so I'm wondering why you're not using it.

Actually, in re-reading your question, it seems like you're not actually trying to do any *dynamics* simulations, rather you just seem to want to plug in a vector of joint values and get positions. In that case, I think the command you're looking for is `jcalc`. This function takes a joint type and joint value `q` and returns the spatial transform `Xj` (which is a 6x6 matrix and *not* a 4x4 homogenous transform!).

Function like `FDab` call `jcalc` to build a chain of transforms, as in:

```matlab
for i = 1:model.NB
  [ XJ, S{i} ] = jcalc( model.jtype{i}, q(i) );
  vJ = S{i}*qd(i);
  Xup{i} = XJ * model.Xtree{i};
```

But I don't think there's any one function that's going to take your `q` vector and spit out a series of positions. You'll have to build your own with `jcalc` and work from there.

Comment: Yes, I had gone through fbkin help and wanted to know about a similar command which might serve the purpose. You mentioned `jcalc`, but then it gives spatial transform. Therefore, I have used another method to verify the kinematics. Thanks for the help.